# sql select actors play together

Tags: postgresql, group-by, correlated-subquery

There are a lot of variations of actor/movies queries. And I can't find correct approach, when trying to select from non-group columns:
I have 3 tables film(film_id, title), actor(actor_id, first_name, last_name), film_actor(actor_id, film_id).
**So, I need to find 2 actors, which play together the most and show output as actor1_last_name, actor2_last_name, film_title for first 5 such films.**
What I'm doing is first, count appearance of actors:

```
select r1.actor_id as actor_a, r2.actor_id as actor_b,
count(r1.film_id) as casted_together
from film_actor r1 inner join film_actor r2 on r1.film_id = r2.film_id
and r1.actor_id > r2.actor_id
group by r1.actor_id, r2.actor_id
order by casted_together desc
```

This returns me table like

```
actor_a | actor_b| casted_together
Name      Name      7
...       ...       6
```

But once I try to add film.title to select it says I can't use it in case it is not in group section (`(select title from film where film_id = r1.film_id) as film_title`). `subquery uses ungrouped column "r1.film_id" from outer query`

How can I use results from above grouping and add there some outer column? In my case it is `film.title`.

Desired output:

```
actor_a_last_name | actor_b_last_name| film_title
Name                Name                Title
...                 ...                 ...
```

Say, George Clooney and Bread Pitt have the most number of films together (9)
And result should show first 5 of 9 lines

```
    actor_a_last_name | actor_b_last_name| film_title
     Clooney                Pitt            Film 1
     Clooney                Pitt            Film 2
     ...                    ...             ...
```

Comment: Can you share desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregate, e.g. `string_agg()` or `array_agg()`:

```
select 
    r1.actor_id as actor_a, 
    r2.actor_id as actor_b,
    count(r1.film_id) as casted_together,
    string_agg(f.title, ', ') as films
from film_actor r1 
join film_actor r2 
    on r1.film_id = r2.film_id
    and r1.actor_id > r2.actor_id
join film f
    on r1.film_id = f.film_id
group by r1.actor_id, r2.actor_id
order by casted_together desc
```

Use the query as a derived table and add actor names and a film title:

```
select 
    a1.last_name,
    a2.last_name,
    f.title
from (
    select 
        r1.actor_id as actor_a_id, 
        r2.actor_id as actor_b_id,
        count(r1.film_id) as casted_together,
        array_agg(r1.film_id) as film_ids
    from film_actor r1 
    join film_actor r2 
        on r1.film_id = r2.film_id
        and r1.actor_id > r2.actor_id
    join film f
        on r1.film_id = f.film_id
    group by r1.actor_id, r2.actor_id
    order by casted_together desc
    limit 1
    ) s
join actor a1 on a1.actor_id = s.actor_a_id
join actor a2 on a2.actor_id = s.actor_b_id
join film f on f.film_id = any(s.film_ids)
```

Comment: Klin, it just returns the list of all possible films, but I still need `find 2 actors, which play together the most and show output as actor1_last_name, actor2_last_name, film_title for first 5 such films`, so group_by should be here definitely

Comment: Use the first query and add to it the joins to actor and film like in the second one. See the updated answer.